# Why does elsif condition get skipped while iterating over an array?

Tags: ruby, conditional-statements

I am iterating over every number in the array to see if array is descending or ascending, but the `elsif` is skipped for some reason.

```
 def is_sorted_and_how(arr)
        str = ""
        arr.each do |num| 

          if num[0] < num[0 + 1]
            str = "yes, ascending"
          elsif num[0] > num[0 + 1]
            str = "yes, descending"
          else
            str = "no"
          end

        end
        str
    end


    Test.assert_equals(is_sorted_and_how([1, 2]), 'yes, ascending')
    Test.assert_equals(is_sorted_and_how([15, 7, 3, -8]), 'yes, descending')
    Test.assert_equals(is_sorted_and_how([4, 2, 30]), 'no')
```

Comment: What rules are there? Is `arr == arr.sort` a valid test?

Comment: Just for info, it is usually helpful for others to post the error message that you are getting.

Comment: arr.sort is valid but I've just started writing code so I was trying to do it without using .sort. Also, thanks for error message tip I'll be sure to include it in future questions it's just that this ran although incorrectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, your `num[0] < num[0 + 1]` does something that differs a lot from your expectations. Here you're comparing *bits of the integer values*, not array items as you might think. It doesn't produce any exceptions because this is a "valid" code, but it is broken logically.

The `each` iterator just yields array elements one by one, so if you want to check two items at once, you have either to yield index (`Array#each_index`) or to use `Enumerable#each_cons`.

But this is not the only problem. The bigger one is the logic itself. In fact, with your current implementation (if you fix the thing I mentioned above) only the last pair of elements will be taken into account (which is obviously wrong) - because each next check doesn't take into account the previous one(s).

One of the possible solutions, for example (just pls note: the task definition is not complete - it is not clear what is the desired output for a "ascending-and-descending" array that has the only element):

```rb
def is_sorted_and_how(arr)
  asc = desc = true

  arr.each_cons(2) do |x, y|
    asc &&= x <= y
    desc &&= x >= y
  end

  if asc
    "yes, ascending"
  elsif desc
    "yes, descending"
  else
    "no"
  end
end

is_sorted_and_how([1, 2])
# => "yes, ascending"
is_sorted_and_how([15, 7, 3, -8])
# => "yes, descending"
is_sorted_and_how([4, 2, 30])
# => "no"
```

Comment: we can add `break unless asc || desc` to the end of the `each_cons` loop in improve efficiency as a fail fast

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that `num` is actually your number and not an array. This should explode on you. A standard `each` statement like that doesn't use indexes. The iterator just passes you the value in the ruby block.

If you wanted to check before and after you'd have to look into `each_with_index` and then dereference the next index on the array.

```
arr.each_with_index do |num, index|
  next if index+1 == arr.length

  puts num > arr[index+1]
end
```

This will iterate over the array `arr` and for each index, it will compare that number vs the next index and print `true` if descending.

Comment: Even easier: [`each_cons(2)`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons).